# "which is {adjective or noun} to {verb}" vs "which IT is {adjective or noun} to {verb}"

Tags: difference

Why do the emboldened phrases below contain **`it`**? I explain why  **`it`** feels redundant, by rewriting the sentences below without the relative pronoun **which**.

> [Footnote] 16 This exploration of 'substantial risk' ends with some good reference back to the set question, **which `it` is crucial to do**.

Richard Glancey, *Q&A Civil Liberties & Human Rights 2013-2014*, [p 25](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Q_A_Civil_Liberties_Human_Rights_2013_20/4BNurvtr0GQC?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=%22which+it+is+crucial+to%22&pg=PA25&printsec=frontcover).

1. ***It*** 'is crucial to do' 'the set question'. This rewrite features only 1 ***It***. After you replace this ***It*** with **which**, this sentence has no more ***It***! Confer (cf.)

> This exploration of 'substantial risk' ends with some good reference back to the set question, **which is crucial to do**.

---

> ‘Poverty’ is a relative term.<sup>103</sup> In *The Independent Schools Council v The Charity Commission for
> England and Wales*,<sup>104</sup> the Upper Tribunal recognized:
>
> > ‘[P]oor’ does not mean destitute even in the context of a trust for the relief of poverty. Broadly speaking,
> > and in the present context, a poor person is a person who cannot reasonably afford to meet a particular
> > need by purchasing at the full cost price the service **which it is the charity’s purpose to provide**.

Paul Davies, *Equity Text Cases Material* 3e 2019, p 204.

2. Again, this **`it`**  feels superfluous. Cf.

"a poor person is a person who cannot reasonably afford to meet a particular
need by purchasing at the full cost price the service **which is the charity’s purpose to provide**"

---

> [41. The class of subrogation under discussion in this case is known as subrogation to an unpaid vendor’s
> lien. I agree with Floyd LJ at para 15 that it is not a concept **which it is particularly straightforward to
> understand**.](https://www.bailii.org/uk/cases/UKSC/2015/66.html)

*Op. cit.* p 909.

3. Cf. "I agree with Floyd LJ at para 15 that it is not a concept **which is particularly straightforward to
   understand**".

---

> **Rule** The standard of care imposed will reflect the level of skill and expertise that the
> professional holds herself out as having, *or* which **it is otherwise reasonable** to expect
> in the circumstances.<sup>120</sup>

Christian Witting, *Street on Torts* 16e 2021, p. 150.

5. Cf. "or **which is** otherwise reasonable to expect
   in the circumstances".

---

> In what circumstances
> he should operate forthwith, and in what circumstances he should postpone the
> further treatment until he has received the patient’s consent, is a difficult matter which
> has troubled the Canadian courts (*see Marshall v Curry* [1933] 3 DLR 260 and *Murray v
> McMurchy* [1949] 2 DLR 442), but **which it is not necessary** for your Lordships to consider
> in the present case.

Mark Lunney, *Tort Law Text and Materials* 2017 6e, p 95.

> That is true; but definition involves limitation, **which it is desirable** to avoid further
> than is necessary in a principle of law like negligence, which is widely ranging and is still in the
> stage of development.

Op. cit. p 134.

> What
> has been described as ‘the chilling effect’ induced by the threat of civil actions for libel is very
> important. Quite often the facts which would justify a defamatory publication are known to be
> true, but admissible evidence capable of proving those facts is not available. This may prevent
> the publication of matters **which it is very desirable** to make public . . .

Op. cit. p 795.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Long answer

You're wrong that the structure is redundant. The relative clauses in the original examples have the dummy pronoun "it" as their subject. The "which" and the "it" DON'T perform the same function.

As you noted, the relative clause can be rewritten as an independent clause:

> 1. "**It** is crucial to do **the set question**."

The subject of this sentence 1 is also the dummy pronoun "it." The object of the verb "to do" is "the set question."

In the original relative clause, the "which" refers to "the set question," and therefore "which" is the object in the relative clause. The relative clause still needs a subject —   the dummy pronoun "it". This "it" matches the structure of the extrapolated independent clause above.

In your version of the relative clause, the "which" is now the subject, so there is no need for dummy "it."

The independent clause version of your relative clause would actually be:

> 2. **The set question** is crucial to do.

Here, there is no "it", and "the set question" is the subject, just as "which" is the subject in your relative clause. This version sounds informal to me and may sound infelicitous to some people.

The dummy pronoun "it" in the original examples is the same as a non-dummy "it" subject in a relative clause, e.g.:

> 3. ... the shoe **which it** chewed.

"It" is the subject in the relative clause, and "which" is the object. "the shoe" is the antecedent of "which".

The independent clause version of sentence 3 would be:

> 4. "**It** chewed **the shoe**."

Again, "it" is the subject and "the shoe" is the object.

We can't have a sentence where "it" is not the subject in sentence 4, because it's not dummy "it".

In sentence 1, because "the set question" (rather than dummy "it") can be the subject, the relative clause does not need to retain the "it" (though it certainly can).

Your other examples follow the same pattern, and they sound felicitous to me. Some sound dubious without the "it." The only one that sounds infelicitous to me is "... a concept which it is particularly straightforward to understand."

Remember that this is all legal writing —  a formal register with rigid style and grammar conventions —  that may bolster the inclusion of dummy "it"  in relative clauses. You'd less likely encounter it in more informal writing and speech.

## Short answer

In sentence 1, *which* is replacing the object of the embedded clause, rather than the expletive *it*. So replace the object of the embedded clause ('the set question') with *which*. We AREN'T replacing *it*. ⟶

> 4. "It is crucial to do which".

Sentence 4 is ungrammatical in English. And we need some device to describe the fact that '*which*' is interpreted as the complement of the verb.  So we must displace *which* onto the beginning of the clause ⟶

> 5. "which it is difficult to do".